Cancelling or aborting an ongoing azure batch transcription request
I ran into a little trouble when using azures cognitive-services-speech-sdk for performing a batch transcription request. To be more specific I was looking into different options for cancelling an ongoing transcription but there did not seem to be any good methods.
So I was wondering if there are any other options or methods that could be use to achieve the result that is needed (cancel the ongoing transcription job).
Have tried looking through different documentations and guides, but seems like there are not any options to cancel the transcription job.

Can you share the code in which language you are trying?

Yea just using the basic code example from this example:https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/blob/master/samples/batch/python/python-client/main.py

One method you can implement to cancel the ongoing transcription process is time out. I tried the below code to set a timeout value of 15 seconds for the thread to join using thread.join(timeout=15). You can adjust this value as needed to fit your specific requirements.
Code :
import requests
import threading
from azure.cognitiveservices.speech import AudioConfig, ResultReason, SpeechConfig, SpeechRecognizer

subscription_key = "<speech_key>"
region = "<speech_region>"
speech_config = SpeechConfig(subscription=subscription_key, region=region)
audio_url = "<BlobSAS_URL>"

response = requests.get(audio_url)
audio_file_path = "<blobfileName>.wav"
with open(audio_file_path, 'wb') as audio_file:
    audio_file.write(response.content)

audio_config = AudioConfig(filename=audio_file_path)
speech_recognizer = SpeechRecognizer(speech_config=speech_config, audio_config=audio_config)
def recognize_speech_with_timeout(speech_recognizer):
    global result
    result = speech_recognizer.recognize_once()

speech_thread = threading.Thread(target=recognize_speech_with_timeout, args=(speech_recognizer,))
speech_thread.start()

speech_thread.join(timeout=15) 

if 'result' in globals() and result.reason == ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech:
    print("Recognized text: {}".format(result.text))
elif 'result' in globals() and result.reason != ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech:
    print("Recognition failed: {}".format(result.reason))
else:
    print("Recognition timed out.")
    speech_recognizer.stop_continuous_recognition()  

Output :
If I gave timeout=15, I got my text output with the input blob .wav file as below,

If I gave timeout=10, I got Recognition timed out messages as below,

